# How can I find the number of distinct shortest paths in undirected graph in linear time?

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory

Given an undirected path, what is an algorithm that number of distinct shortest paths, after inputing the start node u and end node v? The algorithm can depend on |V| and |E|, but must be linear in terms of each one.

A proof that it actually returns the number of distinct shortest paths for any u and v would also be helpful.

Comment: For two paths to be distinct, do they only have vertices u and v in common or just a different path (with possible common vertices)?

Comment: @wcochran Distinct just means any pair of such paths differ in at least one edge.

Comment: Most Dijkstra like algorithms will costruct a tree (rooted at u) yielding a shortest path that you walk backwards from the leaf at v back to the root at u. The problem with what you are asking, is that there could be a combinatorially large number of minimal paths and just enumerating them could be very expensive.

Comment: @wcochran Could I use some implementation of breadth first search, and what would that look like?

Comment: BFS would work well. Each pass you are search 1 level deeper from the root node. So if you encounter v on the nth pass you know the minimal length is n. You could then count the number of times you encounter v on the last pass and quit. I'll think about the details a bit.

Comment: Continuing my thinking ... at BFS iteration n you need to find *all* the (unvisited) nodes that can be reached from iteration n-1. As soon as this set of nodes contains v you are done. Counting the number of v's in the set will tell how many paths lead to v.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On iteration n of a *Breadth First Search* (BFS) we add all the vertices to
a queue that are a distance n from the root. As soon as we encounter the
destination node we have found the shortest distance which is n. In order to
track the number of all possible paths to each node we need to maintain a count of shortest
paths as we go. In the following figure we see there are 20 possible shortest
paths from u to v. As we encounter an unvisited node we sum up the number of
paths from it predecessor.

[image]

The algorithm tracks all of the visited nodes and their counts. Each iteration
visits a new set of nodes and their counts are updated. `Q` holds all the nodes
visited in the previous iteration and `N` holds the new nodes encountered in
the current iteration.

```
for all w in V {  // initialize count's and visited
    count[w] = 0
    visited[w] = false
}

Q.insert(u)
count[u] = 1      // start node (one path from u to u)
visited[u] = true

while true { 

   N = empty      // N = find all nodes adjacent to nodes in Q
   while not Q.empty() {
       w = Q.remove()
       for x adjacent to w {
            if not visited[x] {
               count[x] = count[x] + count[w] // found another path
               N.insert(x)
            }
       }
   }

   if N.empty() return 0  // never reached v

   if v in N() return count[v]  // reached v : return count

   remove duplicates in N  // avoid double counting in next iteration

   for w in N              // mark all nodes in N as visited
       visited[w] = true;

    Q = N                  // prepare for next iteration
}
```

Comment: does this still all run in linear time? I am kind of concerned about the case where we are "remove duplicates in N" |V| times, because of the "while True" condition statement. Same thing for pretty much everything else after the inner while loop, but before the end of the outer while loop; wouldn't they all have to run in |V| times, in the worst case?

Comment: Edit: Or is "while True" a statement that always runs in constant time, and in particular never depends on the input size |V| in the execution of the algorithm?

Comment: The runtime is O(|V| + |E|).  Usually |E| > |V| so O(|V| + |E|) = O(|E|) in the typical case and the depth of the queue dictates the runtime. For a completely connected graph the outer loop only loops once. For a weakly connected graph (e.g. few edges) the outer loop will be taken more frequently but the queue's will be really shallow. If |E| < |V| then O(|V| + |E|) = O(|V|) and you are effectively just iterating thru the vertices.

Comment: So none of the lines outside of the inner while loop are done more than once? For example, the "for w in N"; in one iteration, this would in the worst case take |V|-1 times to loop through size N (like if w was adjacent to the rest of the graphs vertices, and all of these adjacent nodes are added to N). But, as we are talking about BFS, we are running multiple iterations. So doesn't loop's runtime become O(however many iterations * (|V|-1))? Same for the other lines under the inner while loop?

Edit:I guess it would only run for an iter., now that I think about it.What about the other lines?

Comment: Remove duplicates in particular is pretty troubling, if N in the worst case has |V|-1 elements, and we wish to remove its duplicates to a new array, we would have to compare each of the elements of the new array to the one being added from N as we are adding it to this new array. This, to me, may have the effect of running in O(|V|^2).

Comment: Removing duplicates doesn't add anything to the complexity ... you have already done the work of passing thru the queue so making another pass doesn't add anything, Of course this assumes you are using a O(1) lookup table (e.g., a simple array of booleans) to record what you have seen.

Comment: Looking at the looping structure to determine the complexity is deceiving. It is better to think about how the algorithm works. We visit all the vertices and we visit all the edges, but *not* multiplicatively (it doesn't visit every edge for every vertex). Think of the two extremes: (a) one edge per vertex, and (b) and edge between every pair of vertices. In case (a) you will loop |V| times and the queues will have depth 1. In case (b) you will loop exactly once and the queues will have depth |E|.
Of course we are assuming reasonable data structures are being used.

Answer (score 2):

I think something like this is what you're looking for:

Note: Graph is stored as an adjacency list

```
public int shortestPath(int u, int v, ArrayList<Integer>[] adj) {
    Queue<Integer> bfs = new ArrayDeque();
    bfs.add(u);

    int ret = 0;

    boolean[] visited = new boolean[adj.length];

    while (!bfs.isEmpty() && (ret == 0 || bfs.peek() == v)) {
        int node = bfs.poll();
        visited[node] = true;

        if (node == v) {
            ret++;
        }

        for (int next : adj[node]) {
            if (!visited[next]) {
                bfs.add(next);
            }
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

The ideas are in the comments, but essentially you're running a bfs, and tracking how many paths visit v when the first path visits v. Notice how I set the node as visited only after I polled it from the queue, which is needed to count the number of paths.

Let me know if you're still confused

Comment: The number of times a BFS encounters the destination node via a BFS does not yield the number of unique paths from u to v in general. One needs to add in all the number of unique paths to the all the previous nodes as well.

Comment: are you commenting on my code or in general? Because my code already does that

Comment: Nice. It does indeed return 20 on my example graph. It is not obvious how it counts all the paths, but it certainly does.

Comment: The while loop executes 69 times -- I suppose this is from all the paths (and non-paths) generated.

Comment: Non-paths? Also, what test data did you use that yielded 69 iterations?

Comment: By non-paths I mean paths that don't reach v. I created a simple directed graph version that I show in my answer and created a quick test  https://gist.github.com/wcochran/d7e46308ed46caf51112b24972955ac2

Comment: Oh ok. Well then you would be correct. My bfs does indeed generate the non-paths, but there is no way to find all paths to the end without generating the "non-paths" first because you don't know if a "non-path" might be an part of an actual usable path

Comment: Also, my bfs stops when all the shortest paths are found, and won't continue generating all the other possible paths, because of this snippet of code: ```&& (ret == 0 || bfs.peek() == v)```

Comment: Interesting to note that the sum of all the numbers in my bottom left figure is indeed 69. This is the total number of shortest paths to each node. Interesting question... I don’t know why folks downvoted it.

Comment: I upvoted the original question but it has a score of zero. So someone downvoted it and it didn’t get any other up votes.

Comment: Oh... I guess I can upvote it. Personally I think it's a good bfs question